# Concatenate and fill but not continuously

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet that I need to concatenate a couple of cells and then add a number. I want something like:

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
B1
B2
B3
A5
```

But instead, I get:

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
B5
B6
B7
A8
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Thank you
[image: Sample image of my table]

Comment: You don't mention which fields you want to concatenate and which ones you want to add.  Please add more details so a proper answer can be formulated.

Comment: You can start by showing the excel content and the formula you have...

Comment: Thank you both and sorry for not providing all the info I had available, I was on my phone and thought you would understand the text by itself. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Does this work for you? Added a helper column.

Comment: Seems perfect! I'll try it asap!